# Finding $Pr(Y < X < Z)$ where $X, Y, Z$ are random variables with known CDF's

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory

I'm interested in the problem of computing $Pr(Y < X < Z)$ where $X, Y, Z$ are random variables (either discrete or continuous), not necessarily defined over the same support. I found one other thread which concluded that, for the continuous case, we have

$Pr(Y < X < Z) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty Pr\left( x \in [Y, Z)\right)f_X(x)dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left( \int \int_{(x, \infty) \times (-\infty, x)}f_{YZ}(y, z)dy dz\right)$

However, I do not understand the bounds for the RHS. Is $y$ integrated out in $(x, \infty)$ or $(-\infty, x)$?

Comment: Are $X,Y, Z$ jointly independent ?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Yes, I can make that assumption. All the information I have is the pdfs.

Answer (score 2):

You should have:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y<X<Z)&=\int_\Bbb R \mathsf P(Y<x<Z\mid X=x)~f_{\small X}(x)~\mathrm d x\\&=\int_\Bbb R\iint_{(-\infty..x)\times(x..\infty)} f_{\small X}(x)\ f_{\small Y,Z\mid X}(y,z\mid x)\,\mathrm d\langle y,z\rangle\,\mathrm d x\\&=\int_\Bbb R\iint_{(-\infty..x)\times(x..\infty)} f_{\small X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)\,\mathrm d\langle y,z\rangle\,\mathrm d x\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you Graham. It's still slightly unclear to me in which order the bounds of integration are. So I should integrate $dz$ over $(x, \infty)$, and $dy$  over $(-\infty, x)$?

Comment: Yes, @Julian .  It follows the order of the bound variables: $\langle y, z\rangle\in (-\infty..x)\times(x..\infty)$.

Answer (score 0):

$Y<X<Z$ corresponds to limits of integration of $Y<X$, $Z>X$, and $-\infty<X<\infty$ in the order $\int$dydzdx. So you are right, the limits of integration should be $(-\infty,x)\times(x,\infty)$dydz.

Comment: Thank you. So I should integrate $dz$ over $(x, \infty)$, and $dy$ over $(-\infty, x)$?

Comment: Yes, if you do the order dzdydx or dydzdx, e.g. dx last, then those are your bounds. You know to get bounds you simply take the variables one by one and then remove them. So if you start with Y, you do -infinity to X. Then you remove Y from Y<X<Z to get X<Z. Then if you do Z, you do x to infinity. Then you remove Z from X<Z. So finally, X goes from -infinity to infinity.